# I am not sure how to use Serial.println

Tags: c++, arduino

I wrote the code below. But Serial.println occurred errors.

I believe in the code is wrong. But I don't know what is wrong.
Could you tell me how to fix the issue?

```
class Move {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    void go(int w, int h);
};

void Move::go(int w, int h) {
    x += w;
    y += h;
}

Move m;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    m.x = 10;
    m.y = 20;
    Serial.println("at start: x is %d, y is %d", m.x, m.y);  
}

void loop() {
    m.go(10, 20);
    Serial.println("x is %d, y is %d", m.x, m.y);  
}
```

The error is below:

```
c:\Users\a\Dropbox\!Arduino\class\classes.ino: In function 'void setup()':

classes:19:58: error: no matching function for call to 'HardwareSerial::println(const char [27], int&, int&)'

     Serial.println("at start: x is %d, y is %d", m.x, m.y);

                                                          ^

In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Stream.h:26:0,

                 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/HardwareSerial.h:29,

                 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:233,

                 from sketch\classes.ino.cpp:1:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:77:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(const __FlashStringHelper*)

     size_t println(const __FlashStringHelper *);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:77:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:78:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(const String&)

     size_t println(const String &s);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:78:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:79:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(const char*)

     size_t println(const char[]);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:79:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:80:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(char)

     size_t println(char);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:80:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:81:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(unsigned char, int)

     size_t println(unsigned char, int = DEC);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:81:12: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:82:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(int, int)

     size_t println(int, int = DEC);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:82:12: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:83:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(unsigned int, int)

     size_t println(unsigned int, int = DEC);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:83:12: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:84:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(long int, int)

     size_t println(long, int = DEC);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:84:12: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:85:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(long unsigned int, int)

     size_t println(unsigned long, int = DEC);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:85:12: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:86:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(double, int)

     size_t println(double, int = 2);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:86:12: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:87:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(const Printable&)

     size_t println(const Printable&);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:87:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:88:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println()

     size_t println(void);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:88:12: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 3 provided

c:\Users\a\Dropbox\!Arduino\class\classes.ino: In function 'void loop()':

classes:24:48: error: no matching function for call to 'HardwareSerial::println(const char [17], int&, int&)'

     Serial.println("x is %d, y is %d", m.x, m.y);

                                                ^

In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Stream.h:26:0,

                 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/HardwareSerial.h:29,

                 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:233,

                 from sketch\classes.ino.cpp:1:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:77:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(const __FlashStringHelper*)

     size_t println(const __FlashStringHelper *);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:77:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:78:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(const String&)

     size_t println(const String &s);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:78:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:79:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(const char*)

     size_t println(const char[]);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:79:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:80:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(char)

     size_t println(char);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:80:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:81:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(unsigned char, int)

     size_t println(unsigned char, int = DEC);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:81:12: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:82:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(int, int)

     size_t println(int, int = DEC);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:82:12: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:83:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(unsigned int, int)

     size_t println(unsigned int, int = DEC);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:83:12: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:84:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(long int, int)

     size_t println(long, int = DEC);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:84:12: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:85:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(long unsigned int, int)

     size_t println(unsigned long, int = DEC);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:85:12: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:86:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(double, int)

     size_t println(double, int = 2);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:86:12: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:87:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println(const Printable&)

     size_t println(const Printable&);

            ^~~~~~~

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:87:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:88:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::println()

     size_t println(void);

            ^~~~~~~
```

Please tell me what is wrong with me.

Comment: "_But Serial.println occurred errors_" - Copy the errors and put them in the question as text and it'll be easier to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: [`Serial.println`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/println) doesn't work like `printf`. It prints the first argument. The second optional argument specifies base if the first argument is a number.

Comment: Check this out: https://gist.github.com/ridencww/4e5d10097fee0b0f7f6b

Comment: Don't circumvent the warning about too much code, not enough text. It's there for a reason. You've provided pages and pages of error text, only share the relevant error.

Comment: Can you paste in (or provide a link to) whatever documentation said or implied that `Serial.println("at start: x is %d, y is %d", m.x, m.y);` is legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print four things, most often the fastest and most efficient way is to simply call print 4 times.  Print is pretty lightweight compared to involving format strings.  If you're writing for a PC who cares.  But if you're writing for a ATTINY or an UNO or something then you can usually use the savings.

```
Serial.println("at start: x is %d, y is %d", m.x, m.y);
```

becomes:

```
Serial.print("at start: x is ");
Serial.print(m.x);
Serial.print(", y is ");
Serial.println(m.y);
```

Note that I'm using print on all but the last one.  Only the last one is println.  That way only the last one gives a line break and the receiver doesn't have any way to know if I sent with one statement or three.  It all goes in the same buffer and comes out the same way.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using **Serial.println()** as if it where **printf()**. Serial.println(), as specified in the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/println), takes only **two arguments**, the **first** being the value that you want to print through the serial port, and the **second** being the format that you want that value to be sent as.

What you need to do to achieve what you originaly wanted is **first concatenate** the values that you want to send over and **then** send them with Serial.println().

Comment: Thank you gave me advice. Then instead of println what function should I use?
In python "print( 'Hello %s!' % 'World' )"

Comment: You can still use that function, but instead of writtng `Serial.println("at start: x is %d, y is %d", m.x, m.y);` you should write `Serial.println("at start: x is " + std::to_string(m.x) + ", y is " + std::to_string(m.y));`

Comment: With `Serial` on Arduino you can call `print` to construct the output and finish the line with `println`. It isn't necessary to construct the full response ahead of time.

Comment: @AntoniodeHaro Most Arduino installation don't come with a standard library. `std::string` is typically not available unless the user went out of their way to install one. Edit : The Arduino SDK does provide a [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) class though.